# pointer to struct array increment fails

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

```
struct book    *a =  malloc(2 *sizeof(struct book));
if (a == NULL)
{
    printf("Error\n");
    return 1;
}
struct book *p = a;

for(i=0; i<2; ++i){
    printf("Give the titel of no. %d book\n", i+1 );
    scanf("%s", *p->titel);

    ++p;
}
```

The code does not have any errors or warnings but once i input the titel of the 1st book and proceed to the 2nd it crushes. What's wrong with the '++p'?

Comment: It's hard to guess with confidence when you don't show the structure, but the `*p->titel` would require an extremely obscure definition of the type of the title, and you'd not be asking this question if the type were that obscure.  (I mean it would have to be `char **titel` in your structure, which seems implausible.)  Please review how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and provide one — it would only be a few more lines than shown, but it would include the critical information — the details of `struct book`.

Comment: Note that using `%s` means your titles will all be written as a single word, either 'GoneWithTheWind' or 'Gone_with_the_Wind' — or you're going to need to rethink your input format.  `%s` skips leading white space but then stops reading after the next white space (so 'Gone with the Wind' leaves `" with the Wind"` in the input stream).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `scanf("%s", *p->titel);` should have been written `scanf("%s", p->titel);` instead, assuming *book.titel* is a char array. That could explain your observed behaviour.

Could you check?

Comment: This is a good guess — it is probably correct.  But there's an argument that this is as much a comment as an answer.

Comment: this is my answer to your issue :)

Comment: i checked it and now it crashes before the increment part.

Comment: I discovered that there is something wrong with storing the integer page . I deleted this part and now it works fine with the ++p